# Cholesky decomposition issue with subtractive kernel in gpflow

Tags: gpflow

I'm trying the following kernel:

```py
class AperiodicMatern12(gpflow.kernels.Kernel):
  def __init__(self, input_dim = None, period = 1.0, variance = 1.0, 
      lengthscales = 1.0, active_dims = None, name = None):
    super().init(input_dim, active_dims = active_dims)
    k0 = gpflow.kernels.Matern12(input_dim, active_dims = active_dims)
    k1 = gpflow.kernels.Matern12(input_dim, active_dims = active_dims)
    k = gpflow.kernels.Periodic(base = k1, period = period)
    self.base = k0
    self.per = k

  @gpflow.params_as_tensors
  def K(self, X, X2 = None):
    res = self.base.K(X, X2) - self.per.K(X, X2)
    return res

  def Kdiag(self, X):
    return np.diag(self.K(X))
```

When I run it with:

```py
lik = gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian()
k = AperiodicMatern12(1, active_dims = [0])
m = gpflow.models.GPR(X, Y, kern = k)
gpflow.train.ScipyOptimizer().minimize(m)
```

I get:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cholesky decomposition was not successful. The input might not be valid.
>   [[node GPR-0b2840db-15/likelihood_1/Cholesky (defined at /Users/mjg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/models/gpr.py:72) ]]

When I try with the kernel defined as additive:

```py
@gpflow.params_as_tensors
def K(self, X, X2 = None):
  res = self.base.K(X, X2) + self.per.K(X, X2)
  return res
```

everything works fine. X and Y are standardized in both cases. So what is the issue with the subtractive kernel?

Comment: Thanks - that all looks right now

Answer (score 1):

Cholesky decomposition only works for positive-definite matrices. So the Cholesky decomposition operation fails if the input argument isn't positive-definite, or - equivalently, in other words - when the input matrix has any negative eigenvalues. When this happens it is often helpful to actually compute the eigenvalues of the kernel matrix (e.g. `np.linalg.eigvals(tf.Session().run(k.K(X)))`).

There are two distinct cases why the eigenvalues of the kernel matrix might be negative: The most common reason is "almost positive" negative eigenvalues due to finite numerical precision issues - this is why we generally add a jitter matrix (diagonal matrix with 10^(-6) on the diagonal) before computing the Cholesky decomposition in GPflow. The second reason is that there is an error in the computation of the kernel matrix. This is the case here:

```py
X = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)[:,None]  # dummy 1D data matrix
session = gpflow.get_default_session()
K = session.run(k.K(X))
np.linalg.eigvals(K)
```

outputs

```
array([-9.00767547,  1.78835489,  1.51465032,  1.18585391,  0.97478308,
        0.79231475,  0.67625953,  0.5866432 ,  0.52938737,  0.4691057 ,
        0.49032271])
```

Whereas the sum of two kernels (positive-definite matrices) always gives a valid kernel (another positive definite matrix), this property does not hold for the difference *in general*.

**UPDATE:** In very specific cases, the difference of two kernels may be another valid positive-definite kernel. This is the case for [Durrande et al.'s construction of periodic and aperiodic Matern-class kernels](https://peerj.com/articles/cs-50/). Their construction is specific to kernels from the Matern family, and is different from the general implementation of periodic kernels based on *any* stationary kernel that has been implemented in `gpflow.kernels.Periodic`.

GPflow does not provide the Durrande et al. a/periodic Matern kernels out of the box, though it would be easy to implement them on top of GPflow, and the GPflow project would be happy to consider a pull request that adds these kernels to the GPflow code base.

Comment: I'm looking at the work of Durrande et al. (2016; https://peerj.com/articles/cs-50.pdf) and in particular the Jupyter notebook for Fig. 3 in the supplemental material (https://peerj.com/articles/cs-50/#supplemental-information) which has code demonstrating this type of kernel in GPy.

Comment: Ah, I believe that Durrande et al.'s construction only works because of a special link between their construction of a `PeriodicMatern52` kernel with the `Matern52` base kernel. GPflow's generic `Periodic()` class uses a different construction for periodicity. I'll see if I can dig into this a bit further, but you may have to re-implement their `PeriodicMatern52` kernel manually (fortunately, with TensorFlow you won't have to handle the gradients!).

Comment: @MatthewGraham if you want to contribute an implementation of Durrande et al.'s Matern class periodic kernels to GPflow, I'd be happy to review your PR!

Comment: I might when I can around the Cholesky decomposition issue

Comment: @MatthewGraham to clarify, your Cholesky decomposition issue is because your setup does not actually construct a valid kernel. `gpflow.kernels.Periodic(base=gpflow.kernels.Matern12())` (generic periodic construction) is a very different kernel from `GPy.kern.PeriodicMatern12()` (Durrande et al.'s RKHS construction). So to be able to construct your AperiodicMatern12 in gpflow, you first need to implement the kernel computation for Durrande et al's kernel - then you should not have any Cholesky issues.